# Is there a way we can change Bootstrap Magicsuggest search request param from query to own custom tag?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, github, magicsuggest

I am trying to change the request param (query) for magicsuggest to my custom tag, 
have tried passing function in data with my own ajax call, trying to set my custom tag with request.query.
is there any other way to do this? to manipulate the 'dataUrlParams' somehow

```
_mSuggest=$("#inpsuggest").magicSuggest({

    //dataUrlParams: jsonUrlParamObj,   
    displayField: 'fullname',
    //data: myUrlToPost,
    data: function (request,response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: myUrlToPost,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {**searchStr**:request.query},
            success: function (data) {                  
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    maxSelection:1,
    typeDelay:400
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it,

```
_mSuggest=$("#inpsuggest").magicSuggest({

    //dataUrlParams: jsonUrlParamObj,   
    displayField: 'fullname',
    //data: myUrlToPost,
    data: function (request,response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: myUrlToPost,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {**searchStr**:**this.input.val()**},
            success: function (data) {                  
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    maxSelection:1,
    typeDelay:400
});
```